Fetch based on a substring from firebase firestore database
I need to fetch products from the firestore database which title and code fields match a substring (key insensitive)
I've tried in the following way:
export const fetchProductsByTitleOrCodeSubstring = createAsyncThunk('fetchProductsByTitleOrCodeSubstring', async substring => {
  const [titleQuerySnapshot, codeQuerySnapshot] = await Promise.all([
    getDocs(query(productsCollectionRef, where('title', '>=', substring), where('title', '<=', substring + '\uf8ff'), limit(10))),
    getDocs(query(productsCollectionRef, where('code', '>=', substring), where('code', '<=', substring + '\uf8ff'), limit(10))),
  ])

  const titleData = [...titleQuerySnapshot.docs].map(doc => {
    return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
  })

  const codeData = [...codeQuerySnapshot.docs].map(doc => {
    return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
  })

  const data = [...titleData, ...codeData]

  const meta = { method: STORE_METHOD.REPLACE }

  return { data, meta }
})

but it works only if the code or title only starts with received substring and is key sensitive. Is there a way to achieve that?
Thanks in advance!

Firestore does not have substring queries, nor does it have case insensitive matchines, nor does it have full text search capabilities.  You can filter on string prefixes as you have now.  Other than that, you will have to go through a lot of trouble to get full substring matches.  If you absolutely need these kinds of queries to be easy for your app, Firestore is not a good choice for a database.

Or you can use a third-party search service that can help you achieve what you want.
